# Trust SSL certificate via terminal in MacOS

Tags: terminal, wifi, keychain, certificate

I'm trying to setup WPA2 with EAP-TLS authentication using certificates in pfx format.

As adding the certificate to the keychain and changing the Trust settings can be difficult for some users, I would like to script it.

I'm able to import the certificate using the following command:

```
security import certificate.pfx -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

However, the certificate needs to be "trusted" before it can be used to authenticate against our radius server.

Anyone knows how to trust the certificate via the command line (so it can be scripted) ?

Thanks!